# sprintf() negative return value and errno

Tags: c, printf, errno

According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/ `sprintf()` and family return the number of characters written on success. On failure, a negative value is returned. I would assume that an error could occur if the format string is malformed so a negative return value could indicate something other than a `malloc()` error. Does `errno` get set to indicate what the error was?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

C++ defers to C and C does not require or mention `errno` in the description of `sprintf()` and family (although for certain format specifiers, these functions are defined to call `mbrtowc()`, which may set `EILSEQ` in `errno`)

POSIX requires that errno is set:

> If an output error was encountered, these functions shall return a negative value and set `errno` to indicate the error.

EILSEQ, EINVAL, EBADF, ENOMEM, EOVERFLOW are mentioned explicitly: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html

Comment: What does it mean when C/C++ does not require a behavior (e.g. setting `errno` after `sprintf()` failure) but POSIX does? I'm unclear where POSIX fits into the picture - if I wrote C code that called `sprintf()`, I guess I'm calling a libc function...but what determines if I'm getting the POSIX-required behavior or not?

Comment: @StoneThrow the OS you're using determines that. If it's a Unix (including MacOS and Linux), POSIX applies. If it's Windows, it's up to the whims of its libc authors.

Answer (score 5):

I always like the "try it out" method when I have a question like this.

```
char buffer[50];
int n, localerr = 0;
n = sprintf(buffer, "%s", "hello");
localerr = errno; // ensure printf doesn't mess with the result
printf("%d chars\nerrno: %d\nstrerror:%s\n", n, localerr, strerror(localerr));

> 5 chars
errno: 0
strerror: Success

n = sprintf(buffer, NULL, NULL);
localerr = errno;
printf("%d chars\nerrno: %d\nstrerror:%s\n", n, localerr, strerror(localerr));

> -1 chars
errno: 22
strerror: Invalid argument
```

Looks like it gets set when compiling with gcc on linux. So that's good data, and in the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) for `errno` it does mention that `printf()` (same family as `sprintf()`) may change `errno` (in the examples at the bottom).

Comment: Note that the "try it out" method relies on the implementation being standard compliant and the standard not allowing room for different behavior. Sometimes this method can mislead you...